# input type file not properly putting image into image tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, file, input

I was working on something and the question was answered, but i need a different use for it.
I have a jsFiddle of how it works.  http://jsfiddle.net/TbZzH/4/

that is fine and dandy, but when i do it in my code, it will tell me that data.files[0] does not work, and is said to be undefined.  It also does not recognize the FileReader() object.

My code is as follows, using jsFiddle as an example I worked from.

```
$(function(){
  $("input[type='file'].attribute").on("change", function () { updateDesigner(this); });
});
function updateDesigner(input){
  var t = input;
  if ($(input).attr("type") == 'file'){
    try{
      var data = $(t)[0];
      var file = data.files[0];   //<------   FAILS HERE.  .files is an undefined attr.
      var reader = new FileReader();   //<--- working around it, doesnt understand this object as well
      reader.onload = function (e) {
          value = e.target.result;
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }catch(errrrr){
      alert("error putting image into image tag: "+errrrr.toString());
    }
  }
  srcFunction(value); //takes the value and applied it to the src attr of the image tag.
}
```

I want to pipe the data into value and everything would run smooth, but i am not sure what is going on.

Comment: just use `input.files[0]`. I don't know what $(t)[0] is supposed to do?

Comment: Yea, i tried that, and that doesnt work either.  It says that files is undefined etc.  "Unable to get value of property 0, it is null or undefined" because files seems to be undefined.

Comment: Oh, a big issue:  I am running in IE.  I was looking at Object.keys($(input)[0]) and.... IE doesnt recognize ant of them and only really returns a jqueryobjectreference string.  Running it in GoogleChrome has all the objects and gets around this error. ugh.  Browser specific bs is soo annoying

Comment: Don't develop in IE! Ever! :-)

Comment: i wish that was a thing.  I have to, company policy to have a web application which spans across the boards and backdates to approximately IE8

Comment: That's not what I meant. I meant, first develop in Chrome or Firefox, and then test and fix problems you find in IE. This way has helped me personally to keep my sanity, and even reduced development time.

Comment: ahh, yea, i have tried both ways.  going chrome to IE to me isnt a good idea for inexperience as there is less strictness, leaving you with a lot of random garbage when you debug it with IE.... hanging close tags where not suppose to be, etc.

Comment: In that case you should try using a html-validator somewhere in your process.

Comment: It seems to require https protocol to do stuff in IE and have the site trusted.  Luckily i have a SSL Server to do development on to confirm, but it is truely a pain in the a55.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While IE works with some examples, The issues here seem to be related to the websites "trust" and "secureness"

to get a static image to appear on the computer screen, i need to make it a trusted site as well as having the rerouted to https